# How to keep up to date with package updates

Tags: package-management

I've downloaded a number of things, right now for example APR, where the installation instructions told me to download an install file.  However, if this goes out of date, I'll never get a notification as far as I know.  There's a good chance I'll just eventually have something not work and might not know why.  How do you always make sure you're up to date on everything you've installed?

Comment: By installing it from the official Ubuntu repositories or if that's not available, a trustworthy and well-maintained PPA or external repository. If you can't get the software you need from such a source, where the responsibility to provide updates is on the provider side, you have to take care of it yourself.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I expanded it a bit and posted my comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By installing it from the official Ubuntu repositories, or - if that's not available - a trustworthy and well-maintained PPA or external repository.

If you can't get the software you need from such a source, where the responsibility to provide updates is on the side of the repository maintainers, you have to take care of it yourself and continuously check the place where you got the `.deb` package from for new versions.

A third possibility is that some applications contain an auto-updater themselves, which checks its developer server for updates and offers you to install them directly.